# Fundamental Lemma of Variational Calculus for Closed Surface Integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, variational-analysis

The fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations says that if the integral of a function times a test function over an open region is equal to zero for all test functions that vanish at boundary of the region, then the function itself is zero.

However, what's the appropriate generalization for integrals over closed domains, for example, the surface integral of the surface of a sphere? Here we can't even define a function which vanishes at the boundary, because there is no boundary, right?

Comment: Spheres don't have boundaries? Do you mean a solid sphere or a hollow sphere with an infinitesimal thickness? I should think the function $f(r)=R-r$ would vanish at the surface of a solid sphere, right?

Comment: I mean that the domain is the surface of a sphere. No volume but a finite area. The Lemma concerns itself with test functions that vanish at the boundary of the domain. But there is no boundary to a closed surface? For example if my domain was all points inside a rectangle, the boundary would be the rectangle itself. But I’m considering a closed sphere surface there’s no boundary.

Comment: Right, no boundary in this case. So you're just integrating against all (continuous) functions on the sphere.

Comment: @Ted, how would you actually prove that? Maybe starting from the Lemma which explicitly only mentions open domains? That does intuitively seem right though

Comment: No, just do the proof. Assuming your functions are continuous, consider the integral of $f$ against $f$ itself. If the integral of $f^2$ (which makes sense because you have a compact domain) is $0$, you must have $f$ everywhere $0$.

Comment: @Ted, that does make sense. Is this the same argument that is used for the Lemma? Why is there a distinction at all?

Comment: No, in the bounded domain case, you have to use a bump function in order to ensure the boundary condition. So you take a function that's $1$ in a neighborhood of a point where $f$ is nonzero and $0$ outside a small ball around that point.

Comment: Ah so basically what you’re saying is that condition ensures that f is zero over the interior but not necessarily on the boundary?